# Having trouble with Addforce Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Whenever the player hits the enemy, triggers the function and the enemy has to suffer a knockback, but when this happens, after the hit, the enemy will suffer the knockback again if gets close to the player even when doesn't suffer a hit, which shouldn't happen...

here's the trigger (collision) scripting

```
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider hit){
    if(hit.gameObject.tag == "npcSamuraiNormal"){
        hit.rigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward * speed, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}
```

and here is the FSMState for the enemy

```
private void ChasePlayerState(){

    if(dir.magnitude < 1.5f)
    {
        state = FSMStates.AttackPlayer;
        return;

    } else if(dir.magnitude >= 10){
        state = FSMStates.SelectHouse;
    return;
    } else if(enemyHealth <= 0){
        state = FSMStates.Death;
        return;
    }

    /*if(dir.magnitude > 15){
        state = FSMStates.Waypoint;
        return;
    } else if (dir.magnitude < 5){
        rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        state = FSMStates.Shoot;
        return;
    }else if (enemyHealth <= 0){
        state = FSMStates.Death;
        return;
    } */

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(dir), rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, transform.eulerAngles.y, 0);

    rigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);

    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's good that you posted your code, but far better if you paste the *actual* code, not images of it - makes it far easier for people to make edits or copy it to their machines.

Comment: That OnTriggerEnter is very basically "run into npcsamurainormal => add force to npcsamurainormal", no other logic involved. If you want to only knockback when "attacking" you'll need to handle that in the "attack" function.     OnTriggerEnter is called by the physics engine when the trigger collides with something.